# Creating DEM from points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, point, interpolation

I'm trying to make DEM from points in QGIS. 
[image: points that I'm using]
I've read all the other questions regarding the same issue and tried them all. But, none of them worked.

For example, at the end of inverse distance weighted interpolation, it looks like this. 
[image: The result]

Edit: it worked after adjusting the size of pixels.
[image: DEM]

Comment: One possibility: Your CRS is geographic (LatLong) and the extent of the working area is relatively small, compared with the pixel size you have given. Then all your points are sitting within one pixel.

Comment: Please edit your question and specify what CRS your points are in, what are the bounding box coordinates and what pixel size you wish your DEM to have.

Comment: After changing the pixel size, it worked!

Comment: Incomplete answer.  What size did you change from?  What size did you change to?

Comment: @StuSmith I don't remember the original pixel size, but I used 5000 columns for the successful case.